# Calfw - How to integrate with Google calendar?

Tags: calendar

From the man page I read to insert theese statements into `init.el`

```
(require 'calfw-ical)
(cfw:open-ical-calendar "http://www.google.com/calendar/ical/.../basic.ics")
```

What I don't undertand is what I have to put in place of the ellipsis.

Any clue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You have to put in your private or public ical google calender uri.

1. Go to https://calendar.google.com/.
2. Open the settings menu (gear-wheel -> settings).
3. In settings for my calendar click on your name.
4. There unfolds a menu containing one menu item "Integrate calendar"
5. There you find "Secret address in iCal format". Replace the argument of `cfw:open-ical-calendar` with that string.